# How can i prove that about $Det(a_{1},...,a_{n})$?

Tags: matrices

Given this matrix:
$$A=\begin{bmatrix} a_{1}+x & a_{2} & . & . & a_{n-1} & a_{n} \\ a_{1} & a_{2}+x & . & . & a_{n-1} & a_{n} \\ . & . & . &   & . & . \\ . & . &   &  . & . & . \\ a_{1} & a_{2} &  . & . & a_{n-1}+x & a_{n} \\ a_{1} & a_{2} & . & . & a_{n-1} & a_{n}+x \end{bmatrix} $$

How can i prove that to any $n \geq 1$:
$$Det(a_{1},...,a_{n}) = x^{n}+(a_{1}+...+a_{n})*x^{n-1}$$
?

I tried with induction and $R_{n}->R_{n}-R_{n-1}$ and it's not working.

In addition, does this matrix have a special name?

Comment: Try a column operation.

Comment: @hellotinfish It's not working me. Can you try?

Comment: Add all columns to the first column. Factor out $a_1+a_2+\dots a_n+x$

Answer (score 0):

Write $A=B+xI$, where $B$ has equal rows.

Let $e = e_1 + \cdots + e_n$. Then $Be_j = a_j e$ and so $Bv \in \langle e \rangle$, that is, $\operatorname{im} B$ has dimension $1$. Therefore, $\ker B$ has dimension $n-1$. Moreover, $Be = (a_1+\cdots+a_n)e$ and so $e$ is an eigenvector of $B$ with eigenvalue $a_1+\cdots+a_n$. This value and $0$ are thus all the eigenvalues of $B$ because we have found a basis composed of eigenvectors of $B$.

The determinant in question is the characteristic polynomial of $-B$, whose eigenvalues are the negative of eigenvalues of $B$. Therefore, the determinant is $(x+0)^{n-1}(x+(a_1+\cdots+a_n))$.

Comment: How you got that $Ae_{j}=a_{j}e$?  

It is not need to be:$Ae_{j}=a_{j}e +xe_{j}$?

Comment: @J.Roe, sorry, I meant the matrix obtained by setting $x=0$. See my edited answer.